# How to find nonlinear systems of equations information

Tags: openmodelica

Dymola generates a summary of the linear and nonlinear systems of equations.  Here is an example of the Dymola output:

```
Sizes of nonlinear systems of equations: {6, 11, 44}
Sizes after manipulation of the nonlinear systems: {1, 9, 11}
```

Is the same information available when using OpenModelica?  If so, what is the process for generating a nonlinear systems of equations summary?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-d=backenddaeinfo` which prints things like:

```
Non-linear torn systems: 6 {2 1,1 1,1 6,2 9,2 3,2 1}
```

Or you use in OMEdit `Simulate with transformational debugger` and check the equations and blocks in detail. Would in the GUI display something like:

```
non-linear (torn), unknowns: 3, iteration variables: 2
(torn) der(pumps.heatTransfer.states[1].h) := Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT_der(pumps.medium.p, pumps.medium.T, $cse5, der(pumps.medium.p), der(pumps.medium.T))
(residual) Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.rho_pT_der(pumps.medium.p, pumps.medium.T, $cse5, $DER.pumps.medium.p, $DER.pumps.medium.T) - $DER.pumps.rho = 0
(residual) pumps.medium.p * $DER.pumps.rho + ($DER.pumps.heatTransfer.states[1].h - $DER.pumps.medium.u) * pumps.rho ^ 2.0 - $DER.pumps.medium.p * pumps.rho = 0
```

Comment: I tried adding "-d=backenddaeinfo" in OMEdit-Options > Simulation > "Additional Translation Flags", running using the green-right-arrow "Simulate" button, but did not find "Non-linear torn systems" in the "Output" tab.  What am I missing here?  I also tried running "Simulate with transformational debugger" and don't see anywhere that I can check the "blocks in detail".  Where can I find the blocks information?  Thanks!

Comment: The blocks are the equations in the bottom left. And if it didn't say nonlinear systems in the output, it's probably because the count is 0. Did you see the statistics for other blocks?

Comment: Thanks!  I found it helpful to sort the "Equation Browser" summary on the "Equation" column so that all of the "non-linear (torn) ..." entries show up together at the bottom of the list.  For those trying to duplicate this, from the "Modeling" view, run "Simulation > Simulate with Tranformational Debugger" and go to the debugger.  If the debugger does not open on its own, you can open the debugger by clicking on the "Debug more" link that shows up in the "Output" window in the "Message Browser".

Comment: I finally found the `Non-linear torn systems:` output the bottom of the "Notifications" Message Browser tab.  What do the sets of numbers like `2 1` and `2 9` stand for?

Comment: Number of iteration variables and number of torn variables, I believe. Not sure which is which.